# What word would describe 'pick me up' for coffee like beverage

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-request

Consider this expression,

> Most people drink coffee for taste, I on the other hand drink for feeling energized/invigorated in the morning..

What would be an idiomatic alternative for pick me up (in regards to coffee/beverage)/feeling energized. "energized" in this context feels too awkward to me.

Comment: A formal way of saying this could be 'Most people drink coffee for taste, I on the other hand, drink **it** to feel **stimulated** in the morning.'

Answer (score 1):

I like the wordplay that comes with `alive` in this context. Select definitions from [Merriam-Webster online](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/alive):

> 1. : having life : not dead or inanimate
> 2. : marked by alertness, energy, or briskness

So I would say,

> Most people drink coffee for taste, I on the other hand drink to feel alive in the morning..

So the joke is in those two meanings, that I would feel like I have energy with coffee, but also that I would feel dead without coffee (truth).

Comment: What is the world (wide web) coming to that an excellent answer like this has so few upvotes :| Oh well, here's +1 at least :)

Comment: @QuackE.Duck Thanks lol